# Double for loop adding values

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have 2 vectors that only have 4 values in each of them. I want to loop through them and process them together, as the values in both vectors go together in those positions in the vectors.

```
for (std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>::iterator i = volumeVec.begin(); i != volumeVec.end(); ++i) {         
        for (std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>::iterator j = sliceHeaderVec.begin(); j != sliceHeaderVec.end(); ++j) {
            ParseHeader(j->string(), i->string(), sourceDir);  
        }             
    }
```

However, when I run `ParseHeader` it process many more values then what I was expecting. I think I need to fix the arrangement of my for loops but don't know what to do

Comment: How much loop proceedings do you see, 16 or more?

Comment: your loops go through all combinations of `i` and `j` while your text sounds as if you want `i` going from `0` to `3` and `j==i`

Comment: btw to get the indices right, a much simpler example would be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
assert(volumeVec.size() == sliceHeaderVec.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != volumeVec.size(); ++i) {
    ParseHeader(volumeVec[i].string(), sliceHeaderVec[i].string(), sourceDir);
}
```

Or with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
for (const auto& p : ranges::view::zip(volumeVec, sliceHeaderVec)) {
    ParseHeader(std::get<0>(p).string(), std::get<1>(p).string(), sourceDir);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you have a situation like this:

`v1 = { v11, v12, v13, v14}`

`v2 = { v21, v22, v23, v24}`

And you want a loop which process elements from both `v1` and `v2` in pairs `{v11, v21}, {v12, v22}, {v13, v23}, {v14, v24}`.

In such case you can simply use a indexed loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
{
    process(v1[i], v2[i]);
}
```

Before that you might want to check that `v1.size() == v2.size()` to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two collection which you want to run an operation (aka transformation) on, my suggestion would be to use `std::transform` from `<algorithm>`. In my opinion code written with that is well readable:

Suppose you have `vector<int> v1` and `vector<int> v2` and want to add them, you can do:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v1.begin(), std::plus<int>());
```

The last argument could also be an other iterator or a back inserter if you want.